# Convert React function component to a React Class Component

Tags: reactjs

I have a code with refs set using the useState but I would love to convert the code into a class component

```
  const [imageSliderRef, setImageSliderRef] = useState(null);
  const [textSliderRef, setTextSliderRef] = useState(null);
```

for the above and render it in the jsx

[The code with the hooks and jsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdJ5n.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use classes, you can create Refs using React.createRef() and attach the ref to React elements via the ref attribute. Refs are commonly assigned to an instance property when a component is constructed so they can be referenced throughout the component.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
  }
  render() {
    return <div ref={this.myRef} />;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand refs but I am using a template and they have defined it using the useState as shown above in the image and set it to null. How do I convert the above to a class Component?